# Connect QProcess QT5-Style in thread

Tags: multithreading, qt5

I'm trying to write a compression gui that creates a different thread for calling the compression tool and uses a QProcess to pass the arguments.

When connecting with old SIGNAL/SLOT style, signals get tossed around and I can react to them, but trying to connect it without SIGNAL/SLOT doesn't get me any callback.

```
class CommandProcessorMT : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CommandProcessorMT(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    bool cmdProcess(QString tool,QStringList params);
...
private:
    QProcess *m_CmdProcess;
    ...

private slots:
    void processFinished(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus);
    void processErrored(QProcess::ProcessError error);
};

void CommandProcessorMT::compressionLoop()
{
    ...
    m_CmdProcess = new QProcess(this);
    /* Connection works */
    connect(m_CmdProcess, SIGNAL(finished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)), this, SLOT(processFinished(int, QProcess::ExitStatus)));
    connect(m_CmdProcess, SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)), this, SLOT(processErrored(QProcess::ProcessError)));
    /* Connection doesn't work */
    connect(m_CmdProcess, QOverload<int, QProcess::ExitStatus>::of(&QProcess::finished), this, &CommandProcessorMT::processFinished);
    connect(m_CmdProcess, QOverload<QProcess::ProcessError>::of(&QProcess::error), this, &CommandProcessorMT::processErrored);
    while(...)
    {
        /* Do stuff */
        m_CmdProcess->start(tool,params);
        m_CmdProcess->waitForFinished(-1);            
    }
    emit compDone();
}

void CommandProcessorMT::processFinished(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus)
{
    qDebug() << "process Finished";
}
void CommandProcessorMT::processErrored(QProcess::ProcessError error)
{
    qDebug() << "Process Error";
}
```

I know the waitForFinished isn't good and want to get rid of it (that's why I'm using Signals now), any idea why my signals do not connect properly?

Class creating the thread:

```
class BatchConverter : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    BatchConverter(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~BatchConverter() override;
    ...

private:
    Ui::BatchConverter *ui;
    CommandProcessorMT *testi;
    QThread *conversionThread;
    ...
};

BatchConverter::BatchConverter(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::BatchConverter)
{
    testi = new CommandProcessorMT();
    conversionThread = new QThread();
    ...
    testi->moveToThread(conversionThread);

    // Signals to own Slots
    ...
    // Slots to own Signals
    ...
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setAcceptDrops(true);
    ui->progressBar->reset();
    conversionThread->start();

}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but... which version of Qt are you using?  The `QProcess::error` signal was renamed [`QProcess::errorOccurred`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#errorOccurred) in Qt 5.6.

Comment: Using 5.13 
Removed the Error-Process and started handling everything with just the finished-signal. Seems to work now when connected via QOverload.

Maybe this was the problem all along?
Anyway, thanks :D